# get value from parameter MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I get a value from parameter? I have links:
1) `http://localhost:2409/Account/Confirmation/16` or 
2) `../Account/Confirmation/12ds-2saa-fcse`
 I want to get "16" or "12ds-2saa-fcse" in controler method.

my method

```
    public ActionResult Confirmation(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ID is: " + id;
        return View();
    }
```

but it returns null.

Routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

How can I do this?

EDIT!

Everything works perfercly, I don't know why, but restart VS2012 helped.. :O

Now is another problem. Is there any possibility to get `hash` value from this link? `/Account/Confirmation/16?hash=dasdsadasda`. Code below doesn't show hash string..

```
    public ActionResult Confirmation(int id, string hash)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "ID is: " + id + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("hash");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This depends on your route configuration, what does that look like? Also, an `int` parameter will never be null, so what do you mean when you say this?

Comment: Which routes are you using? Just the default, or any custom routes?

Comment: about Routes: look at edit. I mean, that id is "null" because message is not "ID is: 16", but only "ID is: ".

Comment: `"12ds-2saa-fcse"` will be passed to your controller as `null`, which will cause an `ArgumentException`. Does it work for either of your cases (1) or (2)? What does your View look like? Is `Confirmation` inside `AccountController`?

Comment: first problem solved, it was strange - restart VS2012 helped me, and now everything works nice. I have a last problem - please, look at edit. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated problem is that you are encoding the string `"hash"`; not the value of the String variable `hash`.

This:

```
public ActionResult Confirmation(int id, string hash)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "ID is: " + id + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("hash");
    return View();
}
```

Should become this:

```
public ActionResult Confirmation(int id, string hash)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "ID is: " + id + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(hash);
    return View();
}
```